# Creating an arrow with adjustable line thickness ObjectARX C#

Tags: c#, autocad, autodesk, objectarx

Currently im trying to figure out a solution to be able to create arrows that can have different sizes, but im a bit stuck between two possible solutions. One idea is to somehow change the formatting of the arrow leader object, but im unsure on how to do that with styling, or if its even possible to style the arrow. If that isnt possible, trying to creating an arrow manually using a Polyline might be possible, but the only issue blocking me is figuring out the math to do so with only two points. Any ideas?

```
 public override Entity getAcObj()
        {
            Leader acLead = new Leader
            {
                Layer = Layer,
                DimensionStyle = DimensionStyle,
                Dimscale = 15
            };

            for (int i = 0; i < Markup.Locations.Length; i++)
            {
                acLead.AppendVertex(new Point3d(Markup.Locations[i].XCoord, Markup.Locations[i].YCoord, 0));
            }

            return acLead;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternate, you can always use the below code save as `acad.lin`:

```
*Flow,Flow ----<----<----<----<----<----<--
A,1,-.1,["<<",STANDARD,S=.1,R=0.0,X=-0.1,Y=-.05],-
.0
```

And the size can be changed in the properties.